# How do I catch the request url / domain in my REST api?

Tags: php, api, url, rest, dns

This may have a simple answer (and I hope it does) but looking online I only found examples of how to get the current URL/Domain. No where could I find how to get that of the incoming http requst.

My set up is a REST api that handles the typical GET/POST/DELETE/PUT requests. I have to return domain information for clients about the domain they're pulling from. Hence, if a client using my CMS clicks on info, he must receive info about the domain he is logged into (and thus sending the request from).

I chose not to add code here, seeing as my question pertains less to actual code as it does to methodology. Thanks in advance for any and all answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Internet every address could be faked (VPN, proxies etc). It's one of fundamental principles of the network.

You will never could detect with 100% warranty, so the maximum what You could have is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

You could make additional verification for it's existence before to save/process it, but it could cost some additional performance of Your server.

If Your aim is to provide some additional access rules to some methods / data, You should use an other verification mechanism (tokens, passwords etc).

Answer (score 3):

> print_r($_SERVER);

may be it'll useful for you

Comment: $_SERVER globals are all about the server side of things. I'm looking for request(client) information specifically the request domain.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you're looking for the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), accessible in PHP through `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: I read up on HTTP_REFERER but chose not use it due to the security risks it presents. It apparently can always be faked. And also doesn't work well with host sharing. Something some of my clients have. Is there a more secure method prehaps?

Comment: As suggested in another answer, you may want to add the domain as a parameter of your interface. If security is a genuine concern, you can't rely on user-submitted requests at all. How deep is the connection between your application and the referring websites?

Comment: Quite deep. The user would be accessing domain information and client information (no bank accounts, only billing addresses and such). What I ended up doing was including a key that I have both in an external .php file (client side) and on the server in the DB. Comparing these helps me root out fake requests. Its definately not fullproof, but I can reuse the key for other functions aswell so I implented it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no reliable ways to determinate the domain where a request comes from. Maybe you could check the client's IP address and/or the HTTP referer and match it to a set of domains,... but that wouldn't be 100% safe in my opinion.

How about implementing an (optional) parameter for your API calls, which has to be the domainname?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up defining a key constant in an external php file that I will deliver to the client within the CMS. (Already have a bunch of constants anyway).

On the server side I put the key in the database and compare these keys on every request. This is not fool proof but I realized I could use the key for other functions aswell and so I implemented it anyway.

Using this combined with various other security checks I found it unnecessary to have to track the request domain. Thanks for the responses guys!